# Is there a primary shard in DBs in which sh.enableSharding() has not been yet executed?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

MongoDB sharding cluster uses a ["primary shard"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard) to hold collection data in DBs in which sharding has been enabled (with `sh.enableSharding()`) but the collection itself has not been yet enabled (with `sh.shardCollection()`). The `mongos` process choses automatically the primary shard, except if the user state it explicitly as parameter of `sh.enableSharding()`

However, what happens in DBs where `sh.enableSharding()` *has not* been executed yet? Is there some "global primary" for these cases? How can I know which one it is? `sh.status()` doesn't show information about it...

I'm using MongoDB 4.2 version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says:

> The mongos selects the primary shard when creating a new database by picking the shard in the cluster that has the least amount of data.

If `enableSharding` is called on a database which already exists, the above quote would define the location of the database prior to sharding being enabled on it.

`sh.status()` shows where the database is stored:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> use foo
switched to db foo
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("5eade78756d7ba8d40fc4317")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard01",  "host" : "shard01/localhost:14442,localhost:14443",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "shard02",  "host" : "shard02/localhost:14444,localhost:14445",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.3.6" : 2
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
        {  "_id" : "foo",  "primary" : "shard02",  "partitioned" : false,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("ff618243-f4b9-4607-8f79-3075d14d737d"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
        {  "_id" : "test",  "primary" : "shard01",  "partitioned" : false,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("4d76cf84-4697-4e8c-82f8-a0cfad87be80"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
```

`foo` is not partitioned and stored in shard02.

If `enableSharding` is called on a database which doesn't yet exist, the database is created and, the primary shard is specified, the specified shard is used as the primary shard. Test code [here](https://gist.github.com/p-mongo/24e348212a6f625baf8df293b87a7ce2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the detailed test information, which I think is very clarifying. So, if I'm understanding correctly, the primary shard *is not* selected when you do `sh.enableSharding()` on the database but when you initially create the database (typically, by inserting data on its first collection), even before run `sh.enableSharding()` on it. Is my unerstanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is my understanding. `enableSharding` essentially allows data to be stored on all of the shards, but doesn't change the primary shard. You'd need to use `movePrimary` to change the primary shard, if you wish.

Comment: Also note that some databases are special with respect to where they are stored. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#database

Comment: Thank you again for your answer! Maybe what is causing my confusion is the recent addition of `primaryShard` optional parameter to `sh.enableSharding()` in MongoDB 4.2.2. Taking into account the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/#primary-shard: "if you do specify the primary shard for a database and the database is already enabled for sharding with a different primary shard, the operation returns an error and the primary shard for the database remains as before" (continues next comment)

Comment: I think that new parameter is a bit poinless. Because it only allows you to specify *the same primary shard* that the DB already has (when it was originally created, previously to run `sh.enableSharding()`), otherwise it will end in error. Or is something I'm missing here?

Comment: That would use the specified shard as the primary shard. https://gist.github.com/p-mongo/24e348212a6f625baf8df293b87a7ce2

Comment: I think I see the point... the `primaryShard` parameter makes sense in the case DB *doesn't exist before* executing the `sh.enableSharding()` command (I mean, DB doesn't have any collection due to no document has been inserted in it). In that case, it may be useful. Thanks for your testing logs! They are very clarifying :)